# Output not showing on Jupiter Lab for Python

Tags: python, data-science

After print command output is not showing. It happens few time back, after an hour same code runs smoothly. As I am a beginner I don't know much about what's happening.

```
first = 'dip'
last = 'rakshit'
print = (first, last)
```

Comment: You used print as if it were a variable. It should be `print(first, last)`

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the "="

```
first='dip'
last='rakshit'
print(first,last)
```